# I need the phase diagram for ethanol

Tags: phase-diagram

I have been googling for a while and I cannot find a phase diagram for ethanol. Does anybody know of a site that has it? Is there something I should be googling other than phase diagram for ethanol?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Chemistry SE.

Comment: hmm, my interest was coming from a thermodynamics stand point. I did find a phase diagram in the end http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ethanol+phase+diagram

Answer (score 1):

I think that on the Wikipedia [Ethanol (data page)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol_(data_page)) you can find data about triple point and critical point of ethanol.

Comment: I'm not just interested in those points though :(